# Click one div and goes to another on responsive website

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

Hi I am trying to get my website to be responsive. I have two different divs one on the left and one on the right on my website like so...

http://jsfiddle.net/1fupx7aa/2/

HTML

```
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="view"></div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.view {
     width: 200px;
     height:300px;
     background-color: yellow;
     float:left;
}
```

On the website, when I click on the red div, content appears on the yellow div.

I am now trying to make my website responsive, so what I would like to do is on a smaller screen, the yellow div I set to display:none; and the red div width:100% like so...

http://jsfiddle.net/3jmbxumb/

HTML

```
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="view"></div>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

.menu {
    width:100%;
  }

 .view {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Now what I need to do is, when I click on the red div, I would like the content in the yellow div to appear where I would create a back button that would lead back to the red div.

Is this possible?

I have been looking at the bootstrap carousel option, but I don't think this works for my website.

What would I call this and is this possible? Might there be a way where if I click on the red div on a mobile device the red div becomes hidden and only the yellow div appears?

Comment: You can. Attach an onclick event for the red div and hide/show the yellow div if the window width is less than 600.

Comment: SO basically you want to: Call a **yellow menu** that was initially hidden (left) to slide into viewport, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery and having a specific hidden class for small screens - so you don't have to check for screen width in js.

Javascript:

```
var showContent = function () {
    var $yellow = $('#yellow-view'),
        $this = $(this);

    //Hide red and show yellow
    $yellow.removeClass('hidden-small');
    $this.addClass('hidden-small');

    //Add content to yellow view
    $yellow.html('<strong>my content</strong>');
};

$('#menu').click(showContent);
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.view {
 width: 200px;
 height:300px;
 background-color: yellow;
 float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {

.menu {
    width:100%;
  }

  .hidden-small {
    display: none;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s9wkbL9m/2/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use jQuery to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu').click(function(){
        $('.view').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tirpox/3jmbxumb/2/).

Comment: I am planning on using Jquery. I have multiple red divs that you can scroll through and when you click on the red div I would like the yellow div to slide over covering the red completely then when pressing the back button the yellow div sides back and hides.

Answer (score 0):

A quick JS writeup that would work for your scenario

```
$(function(){
$(".back_btn").hide();

if($(window).width() <= 600){
    $(".view").hide();
}

$(".menu").click(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 600){
       $(".menu").hide();
       $(".view").show().text("Some text");
       $(".back_btn").show();
    }
    else {
       $(".view").text("Some text");
    }
});

$(".back_btn").click(function(){
    $(".view").hide();
    $(".menu").show();
});
});
```